# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4. first ever java project - feeling stupid

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have attached the error message in an image. An extra set of eyes would be amazing. I feel like I can't see anything incorrect with the code or spelling.

This is my first ever netbeans project and it is for registering an account on PhPMyAdmin. The database is called java_db and the table is called Account.

[Error Message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSdZy.png)

Java Connect Class

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class javaconnect {
    Connection conn;

    public  static Connection Connectdb(){
         try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/java_db", "root", "");
            return conn;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

SignUp class

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Signup extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Connection conn;
    ResultSet rs;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    /**
     * Creates new form Signup
     */
    public Signup() {
        super("Login");
        initComponents();
        conn=javaconnect.Connectdb();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Back = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        create = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0)), "New Account", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24), new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0))); // NOI18N

        jLabel1.setText("Name");

        jLabel2.setText("Username");

        Back.setText("Back");
        Back.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                BackActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel5.setText("Answer");

        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Mothers maiden name?", "Childhood sporting hero?", "Favourite sports team?", "What is your favourite colour?", " " }));

        create.setText("Create");
        create.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                createActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel4.setText("Security Question");

        jLabel3.setText("Password");

        jTextField4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(create)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)))
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1)
                        .addComponent(jTextField4)
                        .addComponent(jTextField3)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox1, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 146, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(Back))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(create)
                    .addComponent(Back))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(21, 21, 21))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jTextField4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void createActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            try{
                String sql= "Insert into java_db.Account ( Username, Name, Password, Sec_Q, Answer) values(?,?,?,?,?";
                pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
                pst.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
                pst.setString(3, jTextField3.getText());
                pst.setString(4, (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
                pst.setString(5, jTextField4.getText());
                pst.execute();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New Account Created");
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
    }                                      

    private void BackActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        setVisible(false);
        Login ob= new Login();
        ob.setVisible(true);
    }                                    

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Signup.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Signup.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Signup.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Signup.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Signup().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton Back;
    private javax.swing.JButton create;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Your query is missing the last parenthesis : `values(?,?,?,?,?";`

Comment: Something so simple. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Try to close your insert values statment with a  )

```
String sql= "Insert into java_db.Account ( Username, Name, Password, Sec_Q, Answer) values(?,?,?,?,?";
```

to this

```
String sql= "Insert into java_db.Account ( Username, Name, Password, Sec_Q, Answer) values(?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Comment: Something so simple. Thank you very much.